# How to filter the gridview with radiobutton based on a sql query

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I'm using two radiobuttons in advanced search form, they are approved and rejected. When I click on approved it should filter for multiple search box in Gridview and display the result.
There are other three fields 'Updated date','reviewed date' and 'created date' also.
Suppose, I click on the approved button. It should check for the condition updated time is greater than created date and reviewed date is NOT NULL and display the results.

```
SQL query-Select * from test where (updateddate>createddate)and(revieweddate!=NULL) and approved=1
```

For rejected, the same needs to be done with approved=0
I have done the following to radiobuttons in advanced search form.

```
<div class="row"> 
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'Approved', 
        array('0' => 'Rejected', '1' => 'Approved')
    ); ?> 
</div>
```

How can I get the values of all the rows which satisfy the above criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "$criteria->condition" like this:

```
$criteria->condition = ' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 1 ';
```

Comment: This works. But I have another button for reject. How can I place the condition in model class

Comment: if($this->reject){ $criteria->addCondition('reject = '.$this->reject, 'AND');}